# How to make a copy constructor from a liked list

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, copy-constructor

I have a program where I am trying to make a copy constructor and display what I have copied at the end of the program. The problem is instead of it displaying it is giving me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Im just going to give the part where I made the copy constructor. If you need more of code please let me know.

**main**

```
#include "list.h"
int main()
{
list newlist(mylist);
newlist.displayList();
}
```

**list.cpp**

```
#include "list.h"
list::list()
{
head=NULL;

}

list::~list()//deconstructed 
{
  while (head != NULL)
  {
   deleteElement(head->item); //delete next element
  }
}   

list::list(const list&)//copy constructor
{
list L1;
list L2(L1);
}
```

**list.h**

```
class list
{
  public:
   list();
   ~list();
   list(const list&);

  private:
   node *head;  

 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor is not copying anything, and worse it is getting stuck in a recursive loop.  It needs to look something more like this instead:

```
list::list(const list &src)//copy constructor
    : head(NULL)
{
    node *srcnode = src.head;
    node *prev = NULL;

    while (srcnode != NULL)
    {
         node *newnode = new node;
         newnode->item = srcnode->item;
         if (!head) head = newnode;
         if (prev) prev->next = newnode;
         prev = newnode;
         srcnode = srcnode->next;
    }
}
```

With that said, you really should be using the `std::list` class instead of writing your own linked-list manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your copy constructor.

Here, you have not named or used the `const list&` that's supposed to be copied.

```
list::list(const list&)//copy constructor
```

Here, you're creating a new empty list.

```
list L1;
```

Here, you're trying to **call the copy constructor**, in the definition of your copy constructor.

```
list L2(L1);
```

The end result is that your copy constructor creates a new empty list, and then calls the copy constructor again.  Attempting to repeat forever.